# Is WPA2 TKIP+AES with WPS disabled and strong keys secure? What about WPA2 Enterprise against a RADIUS server?

Tags: wpa2

With all the recent vulnerabilities in WPA2 and so many low quality posts/articles in the internet about WPA2 security I am not being able to fully understand the risks of WPA2.

Is WPA2 Personal secure provided that strong passwords (63 bytes random) are used? 
Shall I use TKIP, AES or TKIP+AES in the configuration?

If not, Is WPA2 Enterprise against a Radius server secure? (Again, strong passwords involved).

Comment: No, not really, not even with the right settings WPA2 is strong enough today. Depends on what you want to secure but implementing a RADIUS Server would be your best shot.

Answer (score 2):

- Disable weak/legacy encryption: WEP, WPA, and WPA2-PSK-TKIP.
  Especially, WPA2-PSK-TKIP is oftentimes enabled by default. TKIP
  (Temporal Key Integrity Protocol) uses insecure RC4 for encryption!
  It was an interim solution to replace WEP and was deprecated more
  than five years ago.
- Enable strong encryption only: WPA2-PSK-CCMP.
  CCMP (Counter-Mode/CBC-MAC Protocol) is sometimes called
  “WPA2-Personal” or “WPA2-AES”.

Derived from https://infosec-handbook.eu/blog/hns1-hello-world/

So, WPA2-AES is secure (do not use TKIP). WPA2 Enterprise uses different technologies/protocols. In general, it is also secure.

Comment: Yes, this would be the **Optimal settings for WPA2**, but still it's not "secure" as of today.

Comment: @Azteca That is what I was suspecting. Can you provide any reference?

Comment: @M.E.Refference for what? being the optimal setting or net being secure enough today?